# How to apply default filters to SQL Alchemy Class

Tags: sqlalchemy

We want to apply permission on sql alchemy class. We have a table which contain mapping of user with  they can access.

create table access
(
user_name varchar(256),
strategy_id int
)

Most of our tables contain strategy_id as column.
create table trade 
(
trade_id int,
strategy_id int, 
....
)

Now based on the user using the sql alchemy object for trade table, I want to pass a implicit filter on each query with list of strategy_id that the user have access to.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is `events` in [Sqlalchemy Docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html). This will call the function when any new case run. Like when you run the query for select, delete, update .... This may help you to create a event class which will filter all your query and add strategy_id as default in every where clause.